# ajax form is not submitted, just refreshed and nothing

Tags: ajax, spring, jsp

i have a form to register new users. here is the form:

```
<label for="add-username" class="col-md-4 control-label">Username:</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input id="add-username" name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username"/>
       </div>
         </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="add-password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password:</label>
                 <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input id="add-password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password"/>
                      </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8">
                                    <c:if test="${duplicate}">
                                        <p class="alert alert-danger">I'm sorry that username is already taken.</p>
                                    </c:if>
                                    <div id="validationRegisterUserErrors" class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none"></div>
                                    <button type="submit" id="user-register-button" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

at the end of this jsp file, i have added a script which posts the form in ajax. the script is:

```
  $("#user-register-button").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        registerUser();
    });
function registerUser(){
    var errorDiv = $("#validationRegisterUserErrors");

    $.ajax({
        url: 'user',
        type: 'POST',
        headers:{
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        'dataType' : 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            firstName: $('#add-first-name').val(),
            lastName: $('#add-last-name').val(),
            email: $('#add-email').val(),
            username: $('#add-username').val(),
            password: $('#add-password').val()
        })
    }).success(function(data){
        errorDiv.empty();
        errorDiv.hide();
        window.location="login";
    }).error(function (data, status){
            errorDiv.empty();
            errorDiv.show();
            $.each(data.responseJSON.fieldErrors, function (index, validationError){
                errorDiv.append(validationError.message);
                errorDiv.append("<br>");
            });
    });
}
```

the url "user" is in usercontroller:

```
@ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @RequestMapping(value="/user", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public User registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user, Model model){
        user.setPassword(encoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        user.setRole("ROLE_USER");
        try {
            userDao.createUser(user);
        } catch (DuplicateKeyException e){
            boolean duplicate = true;
            model.addAttribute("duplicate", duplicate);
        }
        return user;
    }
```

but when i click register the page refreshes and in the url is written `http://localhost:8080/signup?firstName=abc&lastName=adcd&email=adc%40ll.com&username=abcdef&password=9376868355`
however no user is added. even if i don't fill out the form and click on register button, no validation error appears and it just refreshes the page. what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your great participation!!!

the problem was in `headers:{...}`.i changed my ajax to below and the problem solved:

```
function registerUser(){
    var errorDiv = $("#validationRegisterUserErrors");
    $.ajax({
        url: 'user',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            firstName: $('#add-first-name').val(),
            lastName: $('#add-last-name').val(),
            email: $('#add-email').val(),
            username: $('#add-username').val(),
            password: $('#add-password').val(),
            homeAddress:$('#add-home-add').val(),
            workAddress:$('#add-work-add').val(),
            phoneNumber:$('#add-phone').val(),
            jobPosition:$('#add-job').val(),
            fieldOfStudy:$('#add-field').val()
        }),
        headers:{
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        'dataType' : 'json'
    }).success(function(data, status){
        alert("User has been added.");
        $('#add-first-name').val('');
            $('#add-last-name').val('');
             $('#add-email').val('');
             $('#add-username').val('');
             $('#add-password').val('');
        $('#add-home-add').val('');
        $('#add-work-add').val('');
        $('#add-job').val('');
        $('#add-field').val('');
        $('#add-phone').val('');
        errorDiv.hide();
        window.location="login";
    }).error(function (data, status){
        errorDiv.empty();
        errorDiv.show();
        $.each(data.responseJSON.fieldErrors, function (index, validationError){
            errorDiv.append(validationError.message);
            errorDiv.append("<br>");
        });
    });
}
```